# how to enlarge image in grid view when mouse over?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to enlarge an image in a grid view while mouse over. But in the script it is not allowed to to write onmouse, onclick or anything. Can uou help?

My script:

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("IMAGE")%>' Height="50" Width="50" Style="cursor:pointer" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("IMAGE")%>' Height="50" Width="50" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Java Script Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".pic").live("mousemove", function (e) {
                var dv = $("#popup");
                if (dv.length == 0) {
                    var src = $(this)[0].src;
                    var dv = $("<div />").css({ height: 250, width: 250, position: "absolute" });
                    var img = $("<img />").css({ height: 250, width: 250 }).attr("src", src);
                    dv.append(img);
                    dv.attr("id", "popup");
                    $("body").append(dv);
                }
                dv.css({ left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY });
            });
            $(".pic").live("mouseout", function () {
                $("#popup").remove();
            });

        </script>
```

Using the  Java Script code

```
<asp:Image ID="img" ImageUrl='<%#"http://gpssurvey.nsps.co.in"+(Eval("IMAGE"))%>'  runat="server" Width="40px" Height="50px" CssClass="pic zoom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Onmouseover is a javascript event. You need just to add "onmouseover" attribute to the desired asp:Image, put a javascript method there, and this method should put a reference to a large image to some hidden div, and make that div visible.

Comment: hi i dont understand how i am supposed to do it.. im using c#

Answer (score 0):

n c# its not easily available. you need to use jQuery for that. Jquery in same like javascript . 
Plugins are provided to magnify image. 
You can use jQuery magnifire plugin.

Here is the code

In html -

```
<div class="magnify">

<!-- This is the magnifying glass which will contain the original/large version -->
    <div class="large"></div>
     <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("IMAGE")%>' class="small" Height="50" Width="50" Style="cursor:pointer" />
```

jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var native_width = 0;
    var native_height = 0;

    //Now the mousemove function
    $(".magnify").mousemove(function(e){
        //When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
        //the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
        //are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
        if(!native_width && !native_height)
        {
            //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
            //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
            //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
            //created this image object.
            var image_object = new Image();
            image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

            //This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
            //width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
            //the image gets loaded.
            native_width = image_object.width;
            native_height = image_object.height;
        }
        else
        {
            //x/y coordinates of the mouse
            //This is the position of .magnify with respect to the document.
            var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
            //We will deduct the positions of .magnify from the mouse positions with
            //respect to the document to get the mouse positions with respect to the 
            //container(.magnify)
            var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
            var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

            //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
            if(mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0)
            {
                $(".large").fadeIn(100);
            }
            else
            {
                $(".large").fadeOut(100);
            }
            if($(".large").is(":visible"))
            {
                //The background position of .large will be changed according to the position
                //of the mouse over the .small image. So we will get the ratio of the pixel
                //under the mouse pointer with respect to the image and use that to position the 
                //large image inside the magnifying glass
                var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".small").width()*native_width - $(".large").width()/2)*-1;
                var ry = Math.round(my/$(".small").height()*native_height - $(".large").height()/2)*-1;
                var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

                //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
                var px = mx - $(".large").width()/2;
                var py = my - $(".large").height()/2;
                //Now the glass moves with the mouse
                //The logic is to deduct half of the glass's width and height from the 
                //mouse coordinates to place it with its center at the mouse coordinates

                //If you hover on the image now, you should see the magnifying glass in action
                $(".large").css({left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp});
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I find a new way to enlarge the image in Grid Using Css

**Css**

```
        .zoom {


    transition: transform .2s;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;

}

.zoom:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(5.1); 

}

    </style>
```

**Asp Tag**

```
 <asp:Image ID="img" ImageUrl="~/Images/DDED.png" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="40px" CssClass="zoom"></asp:Image>
```